# Send a personnalised email from a Google Form

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, google-forms

I'm starting a new project. I have to send a confirmation email when someone purchases a book with my Google Form. By now, I can send an email when you complete the form but I can't put the name of the buyer and the number of books in the email. F.ex : Hello "John", you gonna receive your "3" books in a week.

I've tried something like this :

```
function sendEmail(e) {

  var formreponse = e.responses;
  var itemreponse = formreponse.getItemResponses();
  var number= itemreponse[5].getResponse(); //because it's in the 5th columns of the spread sheets 
  var name= itemreponse[3].getResponse();
```

And then I just write a simple code like this

```
var TextToSend = "blablabla" + name + " blabla" + number + ".";
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, TextToSend, options);
```

But I've got an error message:

> Cannot read property 'responses' of undefined.

And I don't know why!

It's very frustrating for me not to be able to finish this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues:

- When running this function manually, through the editor, no [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) is passed, and so `e` is `undefined`. You should not run this function manually.
- `responses` is not a valid Event property of [Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) triggers.

#### Solution:

- Install an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger, either [manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), so that the function will run automatically when the Form is submitted, and `e` will be populated.
- Change `e.responses` to `e.response`:

```js
var formreponse = e.response;
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects > Google Forms events > Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)

Comment: I've made the change but I have the same error : 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined `
so there is something else haha :/

Comment: @Barnabé I edited my question, you were missing another piece. Please let me know if that solves your issue / need more details on how to proceed.

Comment: @lamblichus So I've had a trigger : When someone submit the form. And I've just change a little bit of the code :

`var nombre = e.response.getGradableItemResponses["Name of the question #1 in the form"];
  var prenom = e.response.getGradableItemResponses["Prénom"];
  var nom = e.response.getGradableItemResponses["Nom"];`


With this change, the email is send to the mail adress **but** the text in the email is not completed by the answers. Instead of having : 
` Hello John, your phone number is 0123456789 `
you will receive :
`Hello undefined, your phone number is undefined`

Comment: @Barnabé, `getGradableItemResponses` returns an array of [ItemResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response). If you want to access one of these `ItemResponses`, you have to specify an index (eg `getGradableItemResponses[0]`), not a string corresponding to the item name.